# Insert rows in Pandas dataframe after comparing with list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe which has four columns. Following is an example of the pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

data = {"Name" : ['A1', 'A1', 'A1', 'A1'], "String1" : ["B1", "B2", "B6", "B7"] , "Values1" : [5, 12, 21, 99], "Values2" : [50, 120, 210, 990] } 

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print( df )

   Name String1  Values1  Values2
0   A1      B1        5       50
1   A1      B2       12      120
2   A1      B6       21      210
3   A1      B7       99      990
```

One of the columns, i.e. `Name` has constant entries only, while two other columns, `Values1` and `Values2` have numerical values.

I have a list (say `String2`) which contains all elements of the column `String1` **and some additional elements**.

An example of `String2` is the following:

```
String2 = [ "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4" , "B5", "B6", "B7" ]
```

I want to find insert all elements which are in `String2` and not in `String1` (i.e. `"B3", "B4" , "B5"`) in the column `String1` in the Pandas dataframe in separate rows. For all these rows where new elements have been inserted in `String1`, I want to put `Null` in columns `Value1` and `Value2`. In the constant column (`Name`), I want to keep the same constant entry (i.e. `A1`).

In other words, following is how I want the new dataframe to be like:

```
   Name String1  Values1  Values2
0   A1      B1        5       50
1   A1      B2       12      120
2   A1      B3       Null    Null
3   A1      B4       Null    Null
4   A1      B5       Null    Null
5   A1      B6       21      210
6   A1      B7       99      990
```

How can I do this using python and pandas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create new DataFrame with `product` for all combinations of unique values of `Name` and then use `left join` in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html), there is no `on` parameter, so joined by intersection of columns names in both df, here `Name, String1` columns:

```
from  itertools import product

df1 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['Name'].unique(), String2)), columns=['Name','String1'])
df2 = df1.merge(df, how='left')
print (df2)
  Name String1  Values1  Values2
0   A1      B1      5.0     50.0
1   A1      B2     12.0    120.0
2   A1      B3      NaN      NaN
3   A1      B4      NaN      NaN
4   A1      B5      NaN      NaN
5   A1      B6     21.0    210.0
6   A1      B7     99.0    990.0
```

Or create `MultiIndex` by [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html) and use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df['Name'].unique(), String2], names=['Name','String1'])

df2 = df.set_index(['Name','String1']).reindex(mux).reset_index()
print (df2)
  Name String1  Values1  Values2
0   A1      B1      5.0     50.0
1   A1      B2     12.0    120.0
2   A1      B3      NaN      NaN
3   A1      B4      NaN      NaN
4   A1      B5      NaN      NaN
5   A1      B6     21.0    210.0
6   A1      B7     99.0    990.0
```

Comment: Deleted my answer as it's same your second approach. +1

Comment: Accepting this in 3 mins.

Just wondering:
The second option works for me

I got an error when I tried the first option in this line:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(product(df['Name'].unique(), String2), columns=['Name','String1'])
```

Which gave this error:

```
TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator
```

Would you know how I can use the first answer also? :)

Comment: @LingGuo - Use `list(product(df['Name'].unique(), String2))`

Comment: @jezrael : Yes first answer failed with this error:

`TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator`

Comment: Both answers work now. I used `list(product(df['Name'].unique(), String2))` in first answer. Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can temporarily set `String1` as the [index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), reindex and reset back to previous form :

```
#hold the current column composition
cols = df.columns

(df 
.set_index("String1")
.reindex(String2)
.reset_index()
 #get columns into previous form
.reindex(cols,axis=1)
 #since Name column is constant we can 
 #forward fill on the Name column
.assign(Name=lambda x: x.Name.ffill())
 )


   Name String1 Values1 Values2
0   A1  B1       5.0    50.0
1   A1  B2      12.0    120.0
2   A1  B3      NaN     NaN
3   A1  B4      NaN     NaN
4   A1  B5      NaN     NaN
5   A1  B6      21.0    210.0
6   A1  B7      99.0    990.0
```

Comment: My initial approach was using then I remembered `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` +1

Comment: Answer working only for one unique `Name`. I guess there are duplicated `Name`s.

Comment: that's a good observation. I'll safely use ```assign``` instead. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to sammywemmy's answer, but slightly different:

```
>>> df.drop('Name', 1).set_index('String1').reindex(String2).reset_index().assign(Name=df.loc[0, 'Name'])[df.columns]
  Name String1  Values1  Values2
0   A1      B1      5.0     50.0
1   A1      B2     12.0    120.0
2   A1      B3      NaN      NaN
3   A1      B4      NaN      NaN
4   A1      B5      NaN      NaN
5   A1      B6     21.0    210.0
6   A1      B7     99.0    990.0
```